# cURL Response in XML - Simplexml_load_string failed

Tags: php, xml, curl, simplexml

I'm making a cURL request into an authenticated area which is working fine; and when echoing out the response everything looks good except for the first part. This is my exact response (with the otherData tag replacing my actual data).

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ResponseStatus>
           <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
           <StatusMessage>Success</StatusMessage>
        </ResponseStatus>
        <otherData></otherData>
    </Response>
```

See how the xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' and then we switch to using " in the actual XML? When I'm trying to load this with simplexml_load_string it fails due to that. I know I could simply do a str_replace, however that isn't really understanding the full issue here.

Comment: The problem lies with whatever is returning the response. Maybe we can see how this is done to help? Btw, good on your for not taking the easy why out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see your php code? I'm running:

```
<?php
    $xml_string =<<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ResponseStatus>
       <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
       <StatusMessage>Success</StatusMessage>
    </ResponseStatus>
    <otherData></otherData>
</Response>
XML;

$xml_obj = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
echo $xml_obj->ResponseStatus->StatusMessage."\n";
?>
```

And it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing all `"` with `'`.

`$string = str_replace("\"", "'", $string);`

The string is being closed at the double quotes.

So the string is printing as

`$string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Response xmlns:xsi="` so obviously using `str_replace()` would turn that `"` it's closing on into a `'` making the string correctly output.

Comment: another kinda bubble gum way of doing it though :/ I didn't know if this was something that normally was expected in a return and a clean way of handling it that didn't involve any kind of data replacing.